# Writing a query for an entire table

Tags: python, database, csv

I'm trying to write a python script that will download data from https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/dataset/g6vv-u9sr and perform different operations on the dataset. I'm having trouble automating the extraction of this data, and am not sure how to properly write a query that will return me the entire dataset (preferably in the form of a csv for pandas). Any pointers?

Comment: Start small. Break the problem into small pieces and solve each piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` module to download the CSV data, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

r = requests.get(
    "https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/sites/default/files/resources/72ed1971c684c81da254c00145da1b47_1647887934/NH_Penalties_Mar2022.csv"
)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text))
print(df.dtypes)
print(len(df))
```

Prints:

```
Federal Provider Number           object
Provider Name                     object
Provider Address                  object
Provider City                     object
Provider State                    object
Provider Zip Code                  int64
Penalty Date                      object
Penalty Type                      object
Fine Amount                      float64
Payment Denial Start Date         object
Payment Denial Length in Days    float64
Location                          object
Processing Date                   object
dtype: object

27881
```

---

EDIT: As @Parfait stated, you can use the url in `pd.read_csv` directly. However, in this case is necessary to explicitly set `enoding=` parameter ("latin1"/"iso_8859-1" works):

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/sites/default/files/resources/72ed1971c684c81da254c00145da1b47_1647887934/NH_Penalties_Mar2022.csv",
    encoding="iso_8859-1",
)
print(len(df))
```

Prints:

```
27881
```

Comment: Why not directly read the URL in `read_csv`?

Comment: @Parfait Doing directly `pd.read_csv(URL)` gives me `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 194512: invalid start byte`, so I let `requests` to do the decoding.

Comment: `read_csv` has an encoding arg. Try `iso_8859-1` or `latin1`, often a typical fix with likely reason of accented names. OP or a newcomer to pandas reading your answer would think [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (perhaps the most extensive of its IO tools) does not support URLs or encoding.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, "latin1"/"iso_8859-1" works. I've updated the answer. Ty! :)